# How to spot the cause of a Kernel Panic in the problem report?

Tags: kernel-panic

I've just got a Kernel Panic. I'm trying to find the source of the problem. I thought it could be the RAM memory but not pretty sure though. This is the report of the kernel but I'm not able to spot the problem in it:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  68434 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          2
Anonymous UUID:                    2A0D2A06-5F0B-4A6C-B7B2-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Wed Aug 22 11:13:58 2012
panic(cpu 1 caller 0x2abf6a): Kernel trap at 0x002227f8, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x80010033, CR2: 0x00000001, CR3: 0x7817a000, CR4: 0x00000660
EAX: 0x00000001, EBX: 0x00000000, ECX: 0x02000000, EDX: 0x52d3d03c
CR2: 0x00000001, EBP: 0x8114bdb8, ESI: 0x0a33c000, EDI: 0x0a33c2c0
EFL: 0x00010286, EIP: 0x002227f8, CS:  0x00000008, DS:  0x00000010
Error code: 0x00000002

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address (4 potential args on stack)
0x8114bba8 : 0x21b837 (0x5dd7fc 0x8114bbdc 0x223ce1 0x0) 
0x8114bbf8 : 0x2abf6a (0x59e3d0 0x2227f8 0xe 0x59e59a) 
0x8114bcd8 : 0x2a1a78 (0x8114bcf0 0x7fff 0x8114bdb8 0x2227f8) 
0x8114bce8 : 0x2227f8 (0xe 0x48 0x10010 0x10) 
0x8114bdb8 : 0x222a9b (0xa33c000 0x847e40 0x1 0xa1d97b4) 
0x8114be08 : 0x24bd60 (0xa33c000 0x1 0xa1d97b4 0x1) 
0x8114be58 : 0x21dbe5 (0xa1d978c 0xa98c898 0x1fd808 0x107) 
0x8114be98 : 0x210a86 (0xa1d9700 0x0 0x14d33150 0x14ce4af0) 
0x8114bef8 : 0x216f84 (0xa1d9700 0x0 0x0 0x0) 
0x8114bf78 : 0x295c57 (0x9c59a28 0x0 0x0 0x0) 
0x8114bfc8 : 0x2a256d (0x9c59a24 0x0 0x10 0x9c59a24) 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: ReportCrash

Mac OS version:
10K549

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386
System model name: MacBookPro5,3 (Mac-F22587C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2287618402958
unloaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43xx    423.91.27 (addr 0xfde000, size 0x1900544) - last unloaded 92821232282
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp    3.2.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt    3.2.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB    3.2.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv    3.2.10
com.vara.driver.VaraAudio    1.0.3
com.AmbrosiaSW.AudioSupport    3.2
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch    2.2.05
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.3d0 - last loaded 30403851463
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM    100.12.31
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.57
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA    2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver    2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl    1.0.20
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver    1.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile    17
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC    1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl    2.10.6
com.apple.kext.AppleSMCLMU    1.5.2d10
com.apple.GeForce    6.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard    201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    303.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader    2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient    2.6.8
com.apple.BootCache    31.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    1.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.7.3
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224    428.42.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager    160.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    2.1.7
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI    4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC    1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons    1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient    142.6.0
com.apple.security.sandbox    1
com.apple.security.quarantine    0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall    2.1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement    142.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction    17
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib    2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction    14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    20
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController    1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface    74.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily    1.8.3fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController    2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily    2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily    41
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily    4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC    3.1.0d5
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    6.3.6
com.apple.NVDAResman    6.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch    207.7
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController    2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    4.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass    2.6.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    3.9.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice    2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice    2.6.8
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter    402.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI    1.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily    2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family    320.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient    4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    1.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.NVSMU    2.2.7
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily    1.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily    1.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    6
com.apple.driver.DiskImages    289.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily    1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    1.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.3.0
Model: MacBookPro5,3, BootROM MBP53.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.66 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.48f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, PCIe, 256 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.42.4)
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD5000BEVT-00A03T0, 465,76 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-868
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8507, 0x24400000 / 2
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8403, 0x26500000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0237, 0x04600000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0x04500000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06100000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8217, 0x06110000 / 5
```

This part seems interesting:

```
unloaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43xx    423.91.27 (addr 0xfde000, size 0x1900544) - last unloaded 92821232282
```

Could it be a problem with Airport ?

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem: the kernel panic only happens if the computer is NOT connected to the power supply. Does this mean that the problem is the Battery? Please help.

Comment: The place in the code where it panics can be worked out from the backtrace. It looks like it's somewhere in the kernel itself, not a kext. You'd have to look up the addresses in the trace (0x21b837 etc.) in the symbol table for your specific kernel, using the kernel debug kit for that version of OSX. Note that this may or may not tell you the *cause*, which can be a lot of things, not necessarily the code where the crash is occurring. What user action triggers the kernel panic?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cascading failure. The ReportCrash process is listed as the problem, and it is highly likely a different process started the issue but the backtrace is corrupted.

This would likely need someone with full access to the system to step through the log as detailed in this KB:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2063/_index.html

Without seeing a few of your crashes (assuming you have several), I would reason that the unload is irrelevant since your system was up 38 minutes and the kext unload happened at 1 minute 32 seconds after boot - so the system ran for 36 minutes after the kernel extension was unloaded.

Since this is a page fault crash, report crash was reading data from a null pointer and this will be hard to diagnose after the fact since the real culprit wasn't located by the log file dump of the panic. You'd need to disassemble the libraries or have a second Mac to symbolicate the kernel and many of the objects to know what happened. Unless you have this exact panic about 5 more times and/or can make it happen at will - digging deeper is going to be very costly and time consuming and exceptionally low chance of success.